# Proxy for test automation and eventual regression testing, or other ideas

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, client-server

I was wondering if anyone could recommend some existing software for working around a slow shared mainframe that is being connected to in a testing and development environment.  Recently I've been refactoring some webpages that are dependent on this server, and I'm stuck with massive delays from making the same queries.  Ideally I want to plug a solution between the the test mainframe and the server on the development system.  For the record, I've been told it's a quirk of the test environment and bears no relation to the performance of the production systems.

My initial thought would be using a caching proxy to generate automated responses to commonly used paths.  Ideally, if done right, having access to both sets of data could eventually lead to a regression suite.

I guess I'm hoping for existing solutions along these lines, or alternate ideas that I might have missed. I'm going to try it personally as a solution first and since it will be limited to a dev environment, so there should be room for flexibility.

The current development environment tends to be java and windows machines, but linux machines are available and with a clean solution, the technology behind it shouldn't matter as much.

:tldr  I'm wondering what is the easiest way to set up a caching proxy to limit repeated interactions with a slow server, ideally with a means to access the cached results for later regression testing.

Comment: Don't you think that "mocking" the system that your are testing (you are trying to test mainframe for regression, right?) during the testing would compromise your results?

Comment: Good point. You wouldn't want to mock the system during formal testing or mock anything that might be subject to change.  In this case, I'm making changes to the layers depending on this being consistent, so it shouldn't introduce any source of error.

Answer (score 0):

There are distributed cache software available on the market, e.g. Oracle Coherence or TIBCO ActiveSpaces. They are typically used with RDBMS, but you can also couple them with mainframe adapters and integration servers from the same vendors.